# Facebook Logout in Objective C With FBSDKLoginManager LogOut Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, logout

I integrated Facebook latest SDK of Objective C. In my app, I am allowing Login via Facebook and Sharing.
Based on user birthday there are discounts. I want to implement Logout functionality, which makes Logout completely from app.

For this I tried logout from Facebook as:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

And, Saved Instance of  `FBSDKLoginManager` at time of login, and when logout

```
[gFacebookSDKLoginInstance logOut];
```

But this method not makes completely logout from Facebook, every time user clicks on button `Login with Facebook` this goes to safari and asking for Authorize permission.

I need completely logout, so that user again need to enter username and password. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[login logOut]` It will not logout from safari. it will only logout from your app.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, So if user want to use another Login credential, so how he can do this.

Comment: Manually logout from safari. No other way! :)

Comment: I thought, this is drawback of Facebook, I implemented Google also in my App, this allows me completely logout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook can not responsible to do Logout in Safari browser.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

`logout` method will just close the session of Facebook in iOS Application.

You have to manually Logout from safari browser.

Comment: I logout from the app then go to Facebook app and login with another account then login to the app, it'll pick up the previous account to login ...is this also the same case right?

Comment: @SanitLee Yes, then you have to logout from the `FBSDKLoginManager` after getting the user information. Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346876/ios-facebook-sdk-4-session/30352673#30352673

Comment: that's very helpful. Thank you!