# Can't login using Facebook Login on iOS 10

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm having a problem with Facebook login on the latest version of iOS 10 and the latest Facebook SDK using Cocoapods. This was working fine, and now it's not working.  When I come back from logging in the access token is nil.  It wasn't nil before.  I do see a message in my log. I Googled the error and could not find anything. I have followed the instructions in the Facebook developer login guide.

> 2016-11-04 10:10:26.122435 Ghosts[833:83731] FBSDKLog: Invalid identifier: 'fb_mobile_login_native_app_switch_dialog_result'.  Must be between 1 and 40 characters, and must be contain only alphanumerics, _, - or spaces, starting with alphanumeric or _.```

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
}
```

FBSDKCoreKit 4.17.0

iOS 10.1.1

Xcode 8.1

Objective-C with ARC

Comment: `fb_mobile_login_native_app_switch_dialog_result` has 47 characters, but only up to 40 are allowed for “identifiers” (here most likely a simple variable name.) So if that’s part of code you have written yourself - fix it; if it is part of the SDK code, file a bug report.

Comment: Does it come back with success but no access token?

Comment: Chris Slowik, I figured it out and posted an answer. I had to use a notification instead of checking immediately after logging in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the access token can be nil immediately after. You have to wait for a notification before it can be used. I think this is a new requirement.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkLogIn) name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

.

That other error message was just a warning I think.

Comment: @deepakssn Check out this answer for Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30347486/211457